# Auto Update for an unreviewed Add On?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, review

We submitted a new add-on some days ago. It is currently under review but this will take some days. On the other hand, it is possible to install the add-on over the app store (with a big hint that it is not reviewed yet).

When we tell our clients to install the unreviewed Add On and the add-on will be approved for example in 2 weeks, will the auto update process work for the users who already installed the add on while unreviewed status?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the auto update function does work for un-reviewed add-ons (or at least it did the last time I had an add-on in this state).  The version that gets reviewed will be the one that is current at the time the reviewer begins reviewing the add-on.

Once the add-on is reviewed, the version to which people are auto-updated is the one which has been most recently reviewed (not any un-reviewed version).  Users will generally have the option to manually update to an un-reviewed version which is pending in the review queue. They are not notified that such a version exists. A fully reviewed add-on has the option of having a beta channel which is auto-updated separately.